# php mail () /r/n and <br> have no effect

Tags: php, email, newline

I've looked at some solutions to this and none of them have worked.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'] . "<br>" ;
    $email = $_POST['email'] . "/r/n";
    $phone = $_POST['phone'] . "/r/n";
    $message = $_POST['message'] . "/r/n";
    $from = 'From: email@place.com';
    $to = 'mail@otherplace.com';
    $subject = 'subject here';

    $body = "From: $name E-Mail: $email Phone: $phone $message"
?>
<?php
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent</p>';
        }else{
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again.</p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

This not only displays everything on one line, but also shows the /r/n and 
 tags as if they were just text.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple:

You need to change all your `/r/n` to `\r\n`

Now in order for `<br>` to be effective, you need to add this in your [`headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Consult the PHP manual for more information on `mail()` and `headers()`

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php**

Comment: I believe that the mailing protocol requires `\r\n`, which won't necessarily be the same as `PHP_EOL`.

Comment: @zneak Then do you think that I should remove what I mentioned about it then? I did find some information on it when I researched it a few minutes ago though.

Comment: Yup, I can now confirm that SMTP header lines need to be terminated with CRLF, so PHP_EOL *shouldn't* be used. Look up section 2.3.7 of [RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt).

Comment: @zneak Thanks, I will do that right away. Much appreciated for the extra information.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I only meant to use `PHP_EOL` in the body text

Comment: @Phil Ok sorry, I didn't fully understand then. I've always used `\r\n` or `<br>` myself, and wasn't aware of that till you mentioned it earlier that it could be used in Email. Which is why I researched it. My fault/mistake.

Comment: Unless you are doing the actual SMTP transaction yourself, your local MSA will probably happily accept your local line ending convention (and in most cases, any common line ending convention).

Comment: @tripleee Extra information I wasn't aware about, thanks. It's obvious that your knowledge of SMTP protocol goes far beyond mine, cheers.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Thanks Shankar, it's a nice number indeed! Thanks for the +1 too, cheers :)

Comment: Short and sweet, +1 :)

Comment: Thanks @zx81 Sometimes, less is more ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your `<br>` won't work because you're not sending an HTML email. Why not simply construct the body text in a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) block, eg

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : 'Not set';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : 'Not set';
$phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : 'Not set';
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : null;

$body = <<<_TXT
From: $name
E-mail: $email
Phone: $phone

$message
_TXT;
```