# Problem with layout of mail in my contact form

Tags: php, forms, layout

I need help for the layout of my contact form, here is my problem :

When I receive the mail from my contact form my /r or /n doesn't seems to work I have all the content of my form on one line, I don't know why.

Here is my code :

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST)) {

    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $speciality = $_POST['speciality'];
    $adress = $_POST['adress'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $txt = $_POST['message'];

    $to = "mymail@mymail.com";
    $subject = utf8_decode("Expéditeur : ".$lastName." ".$firstName);
    $message = 'Vous avez reçu un email de ' . $lastName . "\r\n" .  $firstName . "\r\n" . $speciality . "\r\n" . $adress . "\r\n" . $phone . "\r\n" . $mailFrom . "\r\n" .$txt;
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '.$mailFrom."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$mailFrom."\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    header("Location: /");
}
```

please can anyone help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `\r\n` will only work in text mails (or, if you view the source of your HTML mail). You should be using `<br>` if you send HTML mail (or send text mail)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php mail () /r/n and <br> have no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674079/php-mail-r-n-and-br-have-no-effect)

Comment: Tk all of you its good now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change the `"\r\n"` with the html `<br>` tag

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST)) {

        $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
        $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
        $speciality = $_POST['speciality'];
        $adress = $_POST['adress'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
        $txt = $_POST['message'];

        $to = "mymail@mymail.com";
        $subject = utf8_decode("Expéditeur : ".$lastName." ".$firstName);

        $message = ' 
          <html> 
            <head> 
                <title>Welcome to Website Name</title> 
            </head> 
            <body>

            <p> Vous avez reçu un email de '. $lastName .'<br>'.  $firstName .'<br>'. $speciality .'<br>'. $adress .'<br>'. $phone .'<br>'. $mailFrom .'<br>'. $txt .'</p>

            </body> 
          </html>
        ';

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: '.$mailFrom."\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$mailFrom."\r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        header("Location: /");
    }

?>
```